# Initial Child View Controller

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have a custom container view controller with 4 buttons.  My goal is to have those 4 buttons load up each of the 4 child view controllers.  The problem I am facing now is that I do not know how to make those buttons show the child view controllers.  I have performed `addChildViewController` and the necessary `didMoveToParentController`...however when I cannot use the `transitionFromViewController:toViewController` function since I do not have an already existing child VC in the parent.  So essentially the question is how do I make the navigation screen with 4 buttons( custom container) navigate initially to the first child VC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your initial child controller's view by calling the containment APIs that your mentioned plus adding the subview using `[self.view addSubview:childController.view]`

Comment: now how do I return back to the container screen with buttons?

Answer (score 0):

You can call transitionFromViewController:toViewController and manually perform the view transition in the animations block. You can treat the initial case in a different way by keeping track of the initial state in a property.